# Liability limited to 1 euro

Tags: contract-law, licensing, liability

Often I see a disclaimer to negate any damages caused by software. But I found https://www.pgadmin.org/licence.php which has the last line that says liability should be limited to 1 euro. Is there a reason why a liability cannot be fully negated?

> The Artistic Licence
>
> BY INSTALLING OR DISTRIBUTING PGADMIN AND RELATED SOFTWARE, YOU AGREE
>   WITH THE FOLLOWING DISCLAIMER:
>
> PGADMIN AND RELATED SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED WITHOUT GUARANTEE OR WARRANTY
>   OF ANY KIND. TO THE FULLEST EXTENT ALLOWED BY LAW YOU AGREE THAT THE
>   PGADMIN DEVELOPMENT TEAM MEMBERS, CONTRIBUTERS OR DISTRIBUTORS OF THE
>   SOFTWARE CANNOT AND WILL NOT BE HELD LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT OR INDIRECT
>   DAMAGE OR LOSSES CAUSED WHOLLY OR IN PART BY THE SOFTWARE.
>
> IN COUNTRIES WHERE THE ABSENCE OF LIABILITY MAY NOT EXIST OR BE
>   RESTRICTED BY LAW, PGADMIN DEVELOPMENT TEAM MEMBERS, CONTRIBUTORS AND
>   DISTRIBUTORS LIABILITY SHALL BE LIMITED TO ONE EURO.

Answer (score 1):

It says so:

> IN COUNTRIES WHERE THE ABSENCE OF LIABILITY MAY NOT EXIST OR BE RESTRICTED BY LAW

In many countries it is unlawful to contractually eliminate liability. However, in most of those it would also be illegal to try to limit it to a notional amount.

Comment: ... so, in practice it has *no* effect?  Or it has some deterrent effect?  Or, there are enough places where there is not settled law on the question so the nominal liability *might* be enforceable?  Or this is just wishful thinking by whoever wrote the license?

Comment: @feetwet wishful thinking that probably puts them in breach of any misleading and deceptive conduct law that usually goes hand in hand with prohibitions on excluding liability.